# Determine the effective radius of a gear?

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to determine the gear radius using a ruler by $cm$ but I just don't know what to measure:

1- **the length from gear center point to the end of the gear tooth ?**

[image]

Or

2- **the length from gear center point to the start of the gear tooth ?**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to measure the radius to the point of contact between the teeth. Now this point of contact might move as both teeth roll over each other, and the effective radius of the gear corresponds to the angularly-averaged distance between the axis of the gear and the contact point at the teeth.

If you need a quick and dirty estimate for the average radial distance to the contact point, I would suggest to take the average of the two radii you listed.

Comment: I am no expert about gears. But I would think this means that the
torque transmission is variable, dpending on which of the two gears is
using the tip of a tooth (or can there be more than one working at a
time). If you are doing computation to determine the size for a
minimum torque transmission to be achieved, you might want to chose
the top for one gear and the bottom for the other.  I suspect gear
design is a very specialised topic. Another point is to check how much
of a difference it makes.

Comment: @Babou -- torque transmission would still be constant provided the interlocked gears increase their effective radii with the same factor. And yes, gear design is a very specialized topic.

Comment: @babou Gears for applications like power transmissions are designed with helical teeth so that the average the Johannes proposes is *spacial* and there is no time variance of the effective gear ratio. This is a *very* well studied field and undergraduate mechanical engineers spend quite some time on it (the course is often called "design" or something similar).

Comment: @dmckee and Johannes - I just did what I should have done first: look
at the web. In wikipedia, The design they give (for [involute
gears](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involute_gear)) is preserving
constant angular velocity ratio. The next sentence mentions torque
variation (actually visible on the animation), but is very
unclear. Helical gears seem significantly more complex and less
intuitive. I guess there must be also an issue of velocity difference at the
contact point that causes slipping and wear.

Comment: @babou Involutes are the profile of the teeth in cross-section; they minimize wear because there is never any motion at the point of contact. You run them [helixcaly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gear#Helical) around the cylinder of the gear to arrange both less noise (they engage and disengage smoothly) and no torque variation. It is hard to write about but if you play with a pair of gears built this way you'll get it.

Answer (score -2):

you will have to measure the radius by the second method as in first case the tooth are only for hooking with another gear the do not provide any help in  rotating the system